# Endorser and orderer connections initialized Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error validating

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

Error: Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error validating channel creation transaction for new channel 'mychannel', could not successfully apply update to template configuration: error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied

I'm using fabric blockchain, generated the crypto and genesis blocks already.  When I try to run ./createChannel.sh I'm encountering this issue. I'm unaware of what to do.

I'm facing issue when I run the command `./createChannel.sh`

You can see the process running in the network `docker ps`
[Running Process screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45Xh9.png)

> createChannel.sh

```html
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
export ORDERER_CA=${PWD}/artifacts/channel/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
export PEER0_ORG1_CA=${PWD}/artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
export PEER0_ORG2_CA=${PWD}/artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=${PWD}/artifacts/channel/config/

export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel

setGlobalsForOrderer(){
    export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="OrdererMSP"
    export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=${PWD}/artifacts/channel/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
    export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=${PWD}/artifacts/channel/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp
    #export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=localhost:7050
}

setGlobalsForPeer0Org1(){
    export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP"
    export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=$PEER0_ORG1_CA
    export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=${PWD}/artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
    export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=localhost:7051
}

setGlobalsForPeer1Org1(){
    export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP"
    export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=$PEER0_ORG1_CA
    export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=${PWD}/artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
    export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=localhost:8051
    
}

setGlobalsForPeer0Org2(){
    export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP"
    export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=$PEER0_ORG2_CA
    export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=${PWD}/artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp
    export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=localhost:9051
    
}

setGlobalsForPeer1Org2(){
    export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP"
    export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=$PEER0_ORG2_CA
    export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=${PWD}/artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp
    export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=localhost:10051
    
}

createChannel(){
    rm -rf ./channel-artifacts/*
    setGlobalsForPeer0Org1
    
    peer channel create -o localhost:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME \
    --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com \
    -f ./artifacts/channel/${CHANNEL_NAME}.tx --outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/${CHANNEL_NAME}.block \
    --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile $ORDERER_CA
}

removeOldCrypto(){
    rm -rf ./api-1.4/crypto/*
    rm -rf ./api-1.4/fabric-client-kv-org1/*
    rm -rf ./api-2.0/org1-wallet/*
    rm -rf ./api-2.0/org2-wallet/*
}


joinChannel(){
    setGlobalsForPeer0Org1
    peer channel join -b ./channel-artifacts/$CHANNEL_NAME.block
    
    setGlobalsForPeer1Org1
    peer channel join -b ./channel-artifacts/$CHANNEL_NAME.block
    
    setGlobalsForPeer0Org2
    peer channel join -b ./channel-artifacts/$CHANNEL_NAME.block
    
    setGlobalsForPeer1Org2
    peer channel join -b ./channel-artifacts/$CHANNEL_NAME.block
    
}

updateAnchorPeers(){
    setGlobalsForPeer0Org1
    peer channel update -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./artifacts/channel/${CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID}anchors.tx --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile $ORDERER_CA
    
    setGlobalsForPeer0Org2
    peer channel update -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./artifacts/channel/${CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID}anchors.tx --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile $ORDERER_CA
    
}

removeOldCrypto

createChannel
# joinChannel
# updateAnchorPeers
```

> create-artifacts.sh

```html
chmod -R 0755 ./crypto-config
# # Delete existing artifacts
rm -rf ./crypto-config
rm genesis.block mychannel.tx
rm -rf ../../channel-artifacts/*

#Generate Crypto artifactes for organizations
cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml --output=./crypto-config/



# System channel
SYS_CHANNEL="sys-channel"

# channel name defaults to "mychannel"
CHANNEL_NAME="mychannel"

echo $CHANNEL_NAME

# Generate System Genesis block
configtxgen -profile OrdererGenesis -configPath . -channelID $SYS_CHANNEL  -outputBlock ./genesis.block


# Generate channel configuration block
configtxgen -profile BasicChannel -configPath . -outputCreateChannelTx ./mychannel.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME

echo "#######    Generating anchor peer update for Org1MSP  ##########"
configtxgen -profile BasicChannel -configPath . -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./Org1MSPanchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg Org1MSP

echo "#######    Generating anchor peer update for Org2MSP  ##########"
configtxgen -profile BasicChannel -configPath . -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./Org2MSPanchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg Org2MSP
```

Comment: Looks like you are not using an Admin identity of the org you are using to create the channel.  It would help if you can provide more detail on the actual commands you are running.

Comment: Hello sir, I edited my post. Now you can see all the snippets, if you want a particular snippet please let me know, I'll add that too.